# How to stop `grep` from truncating pipe output

Tags: bash, pipe, echo

Is there any way to have an `echo` at the end of a pipe simply append to the current output rather than removing it all? For example, how can I keep the output for my `cat` and `grep` and add "END OF OUTPUT" to the end of the output from the same pipe:

```
$ cat file.txt | grep 'foo' | echo "END OF OUTPUT"
something foo 
foo
foo something
END OF OUTPUT
```

Similar to how `cat -` works:

```
echo "START OF OUTPUT" | cat - file.txt
```

Comment: `grep` isn't truncating pipe output; `echo` simply doesn't read its standard input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
{ grep foo file.txt; echo END OF OUTPUT; } > output.txt
```

That groups commands without starting a subshell (except with the Bourne shell).

You could do:

```
grep foo file.txt | cat - <(echo END OF OUTPUT) > output.txt
```

(with ksh, bash or zsh) but that creates a few more extra processes and pipes for no extra benefit.

Answer (score 3):

Use a subshell to group output like this,

`(grep foo file.txt; echo "END OF OUTPUT") > output.txt`

Answer (score 1):

This will accomplish what you want

```
$ cat file.txt | grep 'foo' ; echo "END OF OUTPUT"
```

Comment: sorry late reply, didnt see others reply.